# QueryDsl - generate from database

Tags: java, querydsl

Im trying to generate classes from an already existing database using QueryDsl.

When I try to generate classes no code is generated.

**Pom.xm**

My pom file looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>thinclient-example</groupId>
    <artifactId>REDACTED</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <ignite.version>2.6.0</ignite.version>
        <querydsl.version>4.2.1</querydsl.version>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>    

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                <artifactId>querydsl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>export</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jdbcDriver>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</jdbcDriver>
                    <jdbcUrl>jdbc:sqlserver://REDACTED:1433;databaseName=REDACTED;user=REDACTED;password=REDACTED</jdbcUrl>

                    <tableNamePattern>.*</tableNamePattern>

                    <packageName>app.domain</packageName>
                    <exportAll>true</exportAll>

                    <!-- Source where to put the generated classes -->
                    <targetFolder>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</targetFolder>
                    <sourceFolder>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceFolder>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <!-- database driver dependencies -->
                    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
                        <version>7.0.0.jre8</version>
                    </dependency>    
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>    
</project>
```

However, when I run `mvn  com.querydsl:querydsl-maven-plugin:4.2.1:export` the command completes successfully, but yet there is no generated code.

What can I do to make this generate tables from the database?

Comment: Where did you check for generated code? And did you check the `target/generated-sources` and `target/generated-test-sources`?

Comment: I checked in every folder, and yes, including the ones you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter for table names looks wrong:

```
<tableNamePattern>.*</tableNamePattern>
```

Documentation says:

```
tableNamePattern - a table name pattern in LIKE pattern form; must match the table name as it is stored in the database, multiple can be separated by comma (default: null)
```

If you need to generate classes for all database tables, then remove tableNamePattern from your configuration or change it to:

```
<tableNamePattern>%</tableNamePattern>
```